# AccessViolationException when using std::basic_ifstream::get() in C++/CLI, why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, access-violation, visual-studio-2013

When I try to run this:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    std::basic_ifstream<TCHAR> file("TestInput.txt");
    file.get();
}
```

I get an `AccessViolationException` with this stack trace:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection@8()  + 0xae bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended@4()  + 0xa1 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()  - 0x1f885 bytes 
msvcr120.dll!__lock_file()  + 0x2ce45 bytes 
[Managed to Native Transition]  
MyProject.exe!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock() Line 355    C++
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Sentry_base::_Sentry_base()  + 0x55 bytes  
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry()  + 0x32 bytes  
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::get()  + 0x5c bytes 
[Managed to Native Transition]  
MyProject.exe!wmain(int argc = 0x2, wchar_t** argv = 0x054AA3F8) [line # removed]   C++
MyProject.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()    [line # removed]   C
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscoreei.dll!__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x71 bytes 
mscoree.dll!_ShellShim__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x227 bytes   
mscoree.dll!__CorExeMain_Exported@0()  + 0x8 bytes  
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it when trying to read a file?

Comment: Why did I have a feeling it wouldn't happen for me :/

Comment: @chris: Yeah I had the same feeling, not sure why either... are you on VS 2013?

Comment: Yes, although I didn't create the file, so I might as well try that.

Comment: Eh, no, I still can't get an exception.

Comment: @chris: Never mind, for some reason I can't get it to repro standalone either. (I tested it inside another project as the first line of _tmain(), but I guess something else must have run first...) I'll narrow it down, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was compiling with the `_DEBUG` macro (left over from before converting from native).
Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: What does the `_DEBUG` symbol do that causes this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have macro's doing unexpected things.  When you need to figure out what happened in Visual C++, have it dump the preprocessor output.  Details on doing that are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx).